# Client waiting for reply from server though server has sent it

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, network-programming, client-server

I have a code like the one below

Server side:

```
Socket socket = server-client conn socket
try
{
BufferedReader inFromNode = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter outToNode = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
String data = inFromNode.readLine().toString();
String data1 = inFromNode.readLine().toString();
String data2 = inFromNode.readLine().toString();
outToNode .println("Hi");
}
```

Client side:

```
Socket socket = server-client conn socket
try
{
BufferedReader inFromNode = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter outToNode = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
outToNode .println("Hi");
outToNode .println("Hi");
outToNode .println("Hi");
String data = inFromNode.readLine().toString();
}
```

The problem is the client side code is waiting for the reply from the server. I am sure the server side has sent it(I tried placing logs after the send on the server side and they got printed.) Am I overlooking on something here? Is the code wrong in any way?

Comment: try flushing the writer

Comment: ya tried that one too but didnt resolve, infact I gave auto flush in PrintWriter in that second parameter

Comment: try explicit flush. both on server+client

Comment: ya tried that one too but still the problem exists...

Comment: Have you used `checkError()` of the PrintWriter to see if it failed tow write?

Comment: I used it now and got false for it(No errors)

Comment: Why are you calling toString() on a String?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the PrintWriter and the Socket when writing to client finishes from Server. This should ideally fix your problem.